# Why does the output after entering a wrong value is three lines of the message instead of one?

Tags: java

The code entered is :

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class A {

    public void fn() throws IOException
    {
    char ch;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Press C or c to continue.");
        ch = (char) System.in.read();
    }
    while (ch != 'C' && ch != 'c');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        A a =new A();
        a.fn();
    }

}
```

and the output which i get is :

```
Press C or c to continue.
m // i entered value "m" here...
Press C or c to continue.
Press C or c to continue.
Press C or c to continue.
```

Why does the output after entering a wrong value is three lines of the message instead of one?

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what about the output you don't understand? Do you understand what the code is supposed to do, but the behavior is different than what you expect?

Comment: so is it keep on printing!! infinite loop?

Comment: why does it print 3 times "Press C or c to continue" ?

Comment: Those are "characters".  Probably produced by the `System.out.println` statement.  Any other questions?

Comment: (Insert this immediately after the `System.in.read`, inside the loop:  `Systen.out.println("The character value is " + (int)ch);`.  You will see some other values.  Look those up in an ASCII table.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your call to `read()` reads one single character.  When you type `m` and pressed `ENTER`, what was actually sent was three characters:

```
m 
carriage-return
linefeed
```

Your program looped two more times to consume the two extra input characters.

You should be using one of two approaches:

1. Use a `Scanner`.  I don't favor this approach because it's somewhat brittle if the input changes at all.
2. Wrap `System.in` in a `BufferedReader` and use `readLine()` to get entire lines *without* the line terminator, and extract the data you want.

Either approach will handle the different line endings on different operating systems for you.

Comment: Recommendation: use a built-in class like `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` to read user input.